# Python logging within multiple modules (best practise)

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, logging

*Hi all,*

*first of all I wan't to mention, that I'm a beginner in python programming but I wan't to learn it and I have already wrote some scripts. But now it's time to get the best practise skills from you guys...*

**My problem:**

I created a project within PyCharm. My structure of the project is as follow:

```
.
├── executor.py
├── __init__.py
├── bin
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── module1.py
│   ├── module2.py
│   └── module3.py
├── lib
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── lib_1.py
│   ├── lib_2.py
│   └── lib_3.py
├── conf
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── logging.py     # contains the logging dict
└── log.log
```

I would like to start the whole programm by calling the *./executor.py*. How the logging should be formatted and to where it should write the output I would like to define it in the *./conf/logging.py*.

While reading the python logging documentation I saw that this is possible while assign a dictionary. Am I doing this right if I create a *./conf/logging.py* file, or should it be a *.json*?

I also read that for every file I need to create such a logger instance by calling it like that: `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`. Now, do I have to do this in every file, if yes where ? How do for e.g. the *./bin/module3.py* know where to stream the output?

How and where do I need to specify the logging config?

Would very appreciate if you can help me in this case.

Comment: Hi Feteu, you can look into this https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html

Comment: Hi Amit, many thanks for your quick reply. I have already read several of howto‘s specially those from the official documentation. Bur for me it‘s still unclear where to include the configuration. I think I got the point which is about inherit from parent logger instances with the `__name__` as instance-name. The other question I have is: Am I structuring the project right or is there something like a best practise in how to structure a project with logging inside ?